# Config CaptureChangeMysql

Tags: apache-nifi

I tried to change data capture mysql db by Nifi. I used CaptureChangeMysql processor. But i getting error connection refused although I clear state and check passowrd/ user correct, telnet success. Please give me an advice to fix it.

Comment: [link](https://anhsieuviet.com/image/LjkcPE) 'capturechangemysql config'

Comment: [link](https://anhsieuviet.com/image/LjkNFC)  Distribute Map Cache Client Server

Comment: Update your question with the error message and MySQL settings